# Tableau measure count items if between dates

Tags: date, time, tableau-api, measure

What I am trying to achieve is to get **a count of people employed in a particular period**.

I have 3 variables:

1. Employee ID (integer)
2. Hire date (date)
3. Termination date (date or null)

Example

[image: example data]

the formula I am looking for is something like

1. if **termination_date** is **null**
2. then
3. count **employee_ID** in
4. dates between **Hire_date** and max of either **hire_date** or **termination_date**
5. else
6. count **employee ID** in
7. dates between **hire_date** and **termination_date**

This aims to show the dynamic of staff level over the time.
I am new to Tableau, not sure how to even start with it. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This problem will be simpler if you reshape your data to have the following three columns

1. Employee ID
2. Date
3. Action. (where action takes on the values of ‘Hire’ or ‘Terminate’).

Each data row represents one change in status for an employees. If an employee had a termination date, they will have two records in this new format, otherwise just one record showing the hiring date.

You can reshape your data by hand, or leave the original and use Tableau Prep or the Tableau data source page to reshape using a self Union and a few simple calculated fields.

Define a calculated field called Staffing_Change as

```
if Action=‘Hire’ then 1 else -1 end
```

Now you can plot the change in staff level over time by putting exact date on columns and sum(Staffing_Change) on Rows. You can use a quick Table calc, Running Sum, to see the net staffing level. For line mark types, I’d use a step style by pressing on the path button on the Marks card. Otherwise, the chart can give the impression of fractional number of employees.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of stacking the date columns. However, when I am running a time series on the full data, the count isn't shown, just the fact that in some months the number of leavers was greater than starters. It looks like the number of employees was a negative figure in months where the resignations outnumbered hires.

Comment: Does your data structure look effectively like the table you posted? (one row per employee, with a hire date column and a termination date column)? If so, it is easy to (automatically) reshape it into the structure I described - which will then make it much easier to produce the charts you requested. The trick to the reshaping is to use a UNION to combine two copies of the original table, and then use a calculated field to create a single date column - with the end goal of exactly one data row for each hiring and termination event.